# Missing Classes in Android Studio layout folder .xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

https://github.com/spelfit/SpelFit

I am having an issue with my Android app. This is my first one I have a login and register page so far. The fields for email, password and confirm password are not displaying. The error says that two classes are missing but I defined them in the Layout folder `activity_login.xml`

**following classes could not be found:**

> - android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
>   - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding='20dp'
        tools:context="activities.LoginActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@=id/textInputEditTextName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@=id/textInputEditTextEmail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@=id/textInputEditTextPassword"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputConfirmPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@=id/textInputEditConfirmPassword"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonRegister"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:background="@color/colorTextHint"
                android:text="@string/text_register"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/appCompatTextViewLoginLink"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text_member"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText" />






        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

error log[pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgRL0.png)

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4EU.png)

Comment: Please provide the relevant code snippets instead of giving the whole github repo

Comment: @Andreas okay will do!

Comment: it should work.

Comment: okay after closely looking at your code. you are adding id's like this @=id/textInputEditConfirmPassword which is wrong. remove = from ID.

Comment: @HammadTariq Thanks Farhana pointed that out to me I changed it to a +. Im working on another bug now with the Registration Page Variable

Comment: let me know here what is issue you are facing now.

Comment: @HammadTariq okay I will update the question with the error I am getting. The build is successful but the app crashes in the emulator.

Comment: you can connect with me on skype: hammad.sahi1 so we can see stack trace/logs and fix issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not implement following Gradle. Please check these `Gradle` in your `Gradle` file and remember the version of SDK should be same.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you that helped! The fields for email, password and confirm password are displaying now. I had the first line implemented in the Gradle file. I added the second line. android:id="@=id/textInputEditTextPassword" still getting and error that its "Unknown resource type =id"